# Xamarin.iOS support XCode 11.6?

Tags: xcode, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xcode11

Last Xamarin.iOS XCode support is 11.5 for iOS 13.5.
XCode 11.6 stable was released July 15, 2020.
When Xamarin.iOS will support XCode 11.6 for release app on iOS 13.6?

Comment: Still being worked on (not merged yet) : https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/pull/9128

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now Xamarin.iOS support XCode 11.6. Thanks Xamarin iOS' team!!
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/release-notes/13/13.20